# Concatenate variable into $_POST[]

Tags: php, mysql, string, post

While working on task I got following requirement.

In a for loop, I have to insert data in db.
I have SQL query in string with double quotes.
I have to concatenate counter variable inside `$_POST[]`

```
for($k=1;$k<=$total_questions;$k++)
  {
      $sql_insert_survey_question ="insert into survey_questions_options  (question_detail,option_1) values ('".$_POST['survey_que\"$k\"']."','".$_POST['survey_que\"$k\"_option1']."')
      $res_insert_que1=$obj->insert($sql_insert_survey_question);
  }
```

Please need some ideas.

Comment: `$temp = "survey_que".$k."_option1"`; then use the variable `$temp`.

Comment: In most of the answers, you have to do additional care about SQL INJECTION vulnerability. Think when you receive the data like `survey_que1_option1 = "'); DELETE FROM your_table WHERE 1 OR '' IN ('"

Comment: Yes. I have take precautions for that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for($k=1;$k<=$total_questions;$k++)
 {
    $firstValueToInsert = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['survey_que'.$k]);
    $secondValueToInsert = mysql_real_escape_string$_POST['survey_que'.$k.'_option1']);
    $sql_insert_survey_question ="insert into survey_questions_options  (question_detail,option_1) values ('$firstValueToInsert','$secondValueToInsert')";
    $res_insert_que1=$obj->insert($sql_insert_survey_question);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Yogesh. And thanks  for `mysql_real_escape_string`

Answer (score 1):

```
$_POST['name'].$k
```

you can concatenate variable like this in php

Answer (score 0):

Edit like this:

```
for($k=1;$k<=$total_questions;$k++)
{
    $survey_que         =   $_POST['survey_que'.$k];
    $survey_que_option  =   $_POST['survey_que'.$k.'_option1'];
    $sql_insert_survey_question ="insert into survey_questions_options  (question_detail,option_1) values ('".$survey_que."','".$survey_que_option."')";  
    $res_insert_que1=$obj->insert($sql_insert_survey_question);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about     :

```
for($k=1;$k<=$total_questions;$k++)
{
  //store them in a temp variable , so it's easy for me to read
  $value1 = $_POST['survey_que' . $k];
  $value2 = $_POST['survey_que' . $k . '_option1'];

  $sql_insert_survey_question ="insert into survey_questions_options  (question_detail,option_1) values ('$value1' , '$value2')";

  $res_insert_que1=$obj->insert($sql_insert_survey_question);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for($k=1;$k<=$total_questions;$k++)
  {
    $question = $_POST['survey_que'.$k];
    $answer = $_POST['survey_que'.$k.'_option1'];
      $sql_insert_survey_question ="insert into survey_questions_options  (question_detail,option_1) values ('".$question."','".$answer."')";
      $res_insert_que1=$obj->insert($sql_insert_survey_question);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

this will help u in making dynamic insertion of n number of product ..

```
    $loopLength=$_POST['ProudctSize'];

            for ($i=1; $i <=$loopLength; $i++) 
          {
            $productid=$_POST['P'.$i];
            $quatity=$_POST['Q'.$i];
            $rate=$_POST['R'.$i];

           $Insert=mysql_query("INSERT INTO saledisplay ( `saleid`, `productid`, `quantity`, `rate`) 
            VALUES('$oid','$productid','$quatity','$rate')");
    }
```