# concatenate $_POST['childname'.$x] not right

Tags: php, html

i see here i have mine the same:

[Concatenate variable into $_POST[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21899733/concatenate-variable-into-post)

but mine not working, if i echo it, nothing displays

```
 if ($_POST['nochildren'] > 0)
 {
    for($x=1; $x <= $_POST['nochildren']; $x++)     
    {
       if  ( isset($_POST['childname'.$x]) )
       {
          echo $_POST['childname'.$x]; //noting echoes      
          //died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted2.');  
       }

    }
 }
```

and:

```
 <div id="child1" class="formFieldDiv">                        
    <input type="text" name="childname1" id="childname1" maxlength="80" size="30" />
    <label for="childname1">Child 1 Full name*</label>
 </div>
 <div id="child2" class="formFieldDiv">
    <input type="text" name="childname2" id="childname2" maxlength="80" size="30" />
    <label for="childname2">Child 2 Full name*</label>                       
 </div>

 <label for="children">No. of Minor Children* </label>                       
 <select id="nochildren" name="nochildren">
     <option value="0">0</option>
     <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
     <option value="2">3</option>
     <option value="2">4</option>
 </select>
 </div>         

 ["nochildren"]=> string(1) "2" ["childname1"]=> string(6) "child1" ["childname2"]=> string(6) "child2" ["childname3"]=> string(0) "" ["childname4"]=> string(0) "" }
```

what is wrong with my echo line

Comment: What is `$_POST['nochildren']` ?

Comment: `if(!isset($_POST['childname'.$x])` then `echo`?

Comment: oooh i see my mistake DUH!

Comment: i changed it but still no children;s names echoes?

Comment: Please add the output of `var_dump($_POST); die();` to your question.

Comment: it workes now, very strange!

Comment: why don't you make the inputs as an array? it would be easier

Answer (score 0):

Here's for your HTML:

```
 <div id="child1" class="formFieldDiv">                        
    <input type="text" name="childname[]" maxlength="80" size="30" />
    <label for="childname1">Child 1 Full name*</label>
 </div>
 <div id="child2" class="formFieldDiv">
    <input type="text" name="childname[]" maxlength="80" size="30" />
    <label for="childname2">Child 2 Full name*</label>                       
 </div>
```

And this is the PHP:

```
$input = array();
$input = $_POST['childname'];
foreach($input as $i){//if input is null it won't show anything
    echo $i."<br>";
    }
```

It's easier, right?

Answer (score 0):

```
 if ($_POST['nochildren'] > 0)
 {
    for($x=1; $x <= $_POST['nochildren']; $x++)     
    {
      $id='childname['.$x.']'; //added code
      if ( isset($_POST[$id) )
      {
         echo $_POST[$id];           
      }

    }
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, Check are you getting value in $_POST

```
print_r($_POST);
```

or try with this:

```
if(isset($_POST['nochildren'])){
if ($_POST['nochildren'] > 0)
 {
    for($x=1; $x <= $_POST['nochildren']; $x++)     
    {
       if  (isset($_POST['childname'.$x]) )
       {
          echo $_POST['childname'.$x]; //noting echoes      
          //died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted2.');  
       }

    }
 }
}
else
    echo 'no post values';
```

Sometimes, we think we must be getting value here. But, it not there.

Comment: i get echo $_POST['nochildren'] if i selected 2 from drop down 2 echoes.

Comment: `if  ( !isset($_POST['childname'.$x]) ) { echo $_POST['childname'.$x];` -- If it's not set there is nothing to print, your logic is broken.

Comment: please do print_r($_POST) at beginning and see what post values u are getting.